# Meaning of verbal suffix ～てくたっとしてしまう

Tags: grammar, verbs, compounds, auxiliaries

I've come across several cases of verbs with the suffix ～てくたっとしてしまう, but am unsure how to break this suffix down, or what it means exactly. It seems that this is the て-form of the base verb, followed by something that looks like くたっ, perhaps followed by the particle と and the verb する in the て-form, followed by the auxiliary verb しまう, but I'm having no luck finding a grammatical description of the middle part here (くたっとする?).

A quick Google search finds many examples of sentences using this kind of structure, such as:

- きんぴらごぼうなども、そのまま鍋に入れておくと、余熱で火が通ってくたっとしてしまうので同じような処理をする。
- レザーのクラッチバックというと重くてくたっとしてしまうイメージでしたが、これは全く違う印象でした。
- 冬はさむくてくたっとしてしまうので、暖かいお部屋に入れてあげるか、いっそ球根（というかイモですね）で越冬させるか。

Would anyone be able to clarify the grammatical function at work here?

Comment: まるで文法に関する質問のように聞かれていますが、実は「くたっと」の意味がそもそも理解できていないのでは？要するに、基本的には文法ではなく語彙に関する質問なのでは？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

くたっ is a [mimetic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30335/5010) word meaning something like "floppy", "tired", "withered", etc. It's a variation of [くたくた / ぐだぐだ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%9F). くたっとする means "to become withered", etc.

When you have seen an unfamiliar mimetic/onomatopoeic word in the form of ～っと, it's a good idea to repeat the mimetic/onomatopoeic part and look it up in a dictionary. (e.g., look up にょきにょき instead of にょきっと) See: [How are the giongo/gitaigo double form and tto form related (きらきら vs. きらっと)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1479/5010)

You have parsed the remaining part correctly. To clarify, ～てくたっとしてしまう is not a set "suffix" at all. It's just four words: ～て + くたっと + して + しまう, meaning something like "and (it) ends up becoming floppy".